# minimum MacBook and specs required for iOS development

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this MacBook 13":

```
http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-early-2008-penryn-specs.html
```

I checked on the app store and it says Xcode requires OSX version 10.8.4 Mountain Lion and later. Although this page from apple dev center says the requirement is snow leopard 10.6.8 and later:

```
https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html
```

The Mac on the page above says it's upgradeable to 10.7.5 Lion.

Is this MacBook sufficient for iOS development,and if so, what iOS version does it support?

Much appreciated,

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is regarding hardware and software.

Comment: well I'm a beginner in iOS development and I wanted to seek professional help.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that your question is off-topic for this website.

Comment: If this question is off-topic. Please guide me to where i can seek an answer to my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From apple help center..

> What are the requirements for developing with the iOS SDK and Xcode?
>
> To develop with the iOS SDK and Xcode, you must have an Intel-based
>   Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or later and you must be registered
>   as an Apple Developer

.

Depending to the version of xcode you want to use, you need to have the proper OS in your Mac machine. For example xcode 5 iOS 7 requires 10.8.4 or later versus the older version of xcode that would run on older machines. I suggest you keep up with the latest since the technologies available in xcode 5 are fun to work with.

In addition your Mac 2008 might run up to iOS 5 xcode 4 although it is hard to find the link to the sdk. And as far as development is concerned apple requires all new and updates to be build and support iOS 7 from February 2014.

Comment: Why would anyone want to down vote this answer is beyond me.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I think some people down vote answers (regardless of their merit) if the question is deemed off topic or a duplicate. I've seen it before.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank man. I know you didn't. That's not your style. I learn a lot from your answers on different topics.